# Alternative authoring script from USB

Tags: macos

The autorun script is deprecated on MacOS. my idea is to write a script ( starting on boot) which "see"  when the content of volumes folder changes. When My USB is mounted.

Comment: Good - what was your question?

Comment: How I can do it

Comment: It was removed because it was a massive security risk - anyone can insert a USB and it could contain a one-line script that wipes your entire Mac. Do you know `bash` scripting? If so, it's a simple `while` loop that gets a list of Volumes folder and if it changes, it does something, then it sleeps 10 seconds before going around again.

Comment: I don't like this solution because the loop will never stop.

Comment: Why? If you see a new Volume, do something and then break out of the loop.